# Make to install dependencies in multiple projects Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a `Makefile` with multiple subprojects and set its build dependencies.

Now I want to be able to selectively `make install` some of those subprojects but include the dependencies in the installation.
How can I do this?

Suppose a `Makefile` like this:

```
lib1:

lib2:

proj1: lib1

proj2: lib2

proj3: lib1 lib2

install_%:  $*
    make -C $* install

install:    $(addprefix install_,$(SUBDIRS) )
```

And I'd like to be able to do, from command line, things like:

```
make install SUBDIRS=proj1
```

or

```
make install SUBDIRS=proj3
```

My rules will try to build and install "proj3", but:

- Will fail if any lib is not built.
- Even if it finds the needed libs, those will not be installed along the program.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In the makefile for dependent projects and include the makefiles for dependencies and write rules to express the dependency:

proj3/Makefile:

```
include ../lib1/Makefile
include ../lib2/Makefile

proj3: lib1 lib2
    $(CC) ....

install: proj3 install_lib1 install_lib2
    cp ...
```

lib1/Makefile:

```
lib1: # ....
    $(CC) ....

install_lib1: # ....
    cp ...
```